# vhdl multiplicationof 2 numbers

Tags: vhdl

[image: My code]I am a new at vhdl and i have to multiplication two unsigned vectors like we all did in high scool

so i wrote the program and it dose compile but the result is not good.

The logic looks ok but still it dose  not work can any one help.
I could not get how to place code here so please see the image attached.

Thx

Comment: Just paste you code in, highlight it and use the toolbar to put "code" formatting on it.  While you're at it, tell us what "doesn't work" about it in some detail.

Answer (score 2):

When writing VHDL you'll first and foremost need to think hardware. Even though various statements may look similar to what you know from other languages, many of these behave differently, as they are mapped to hardware and evaluated in parallel rather than sequentially.

For instance, `for` loops in VHDL do not iterate through the loop, but rather replicate the loop contents and evaluate all of these in parallel. So your idea of accumulating `temp` will not work, as all values of `temp1` would be available at the same time instead of one after another.

The easy way of handling multiplication is to just use the `*` operator, as many synthesizers will pick this up and automatically instantiate the necessary hardware. I assume this is some form of exercise though, where you need to implement the functionality yourself - so just ditch the  `for` loop and store the intermediate results in their own variable, and then add them all up in the end.